# Bot framework authentication with Azure AD B2C

Tags: botframework, azure-ad-b2c, azure-bot-service

How to use Azure AD B2c authentication with bot framework? Not sure which authentication option to use and what parameters to set, didn't find any official documentation, I found this but it's not for Azure AD B2C

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-samplehttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample

Comment: I see that you linked to some Teams documentation. Are you using Teams? And have you read the Azure AD B2C documentation?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [BotAuth.AADb2c package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BotAuth.AADb2c/0.1.0-alpha) which is a Azure AD B2C authentication provider for using with the BotAuth package in a Bot Framework/BotBuilder Project.

Here is the [Azure AD B2C Sample code](https://github.com/richdizz/BotAuth/tree/master/CSharp/SampleAADb2cBot) for your reference.